# Magento - Change Shipping Method - Error Text

Tags: shipping, messages

Currently when a customer puts an incorrect Zip and State under the Shipping Method area is the following text "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.
May be due the weight of the items in your cart. Please, contact us to arrange the shipment."

I would like to change this text to be more appropriate such as "Please verify your State and Zip Code".

How can I update this text?

Comment: That isn't default Magento wording. Did you do a search of your code for that phrase? Depending on how your developer set this up, it could be in the code or it could be in the database.

Comment: Where would I start to look? I'm used to simple HTML at best. The magento management system is very foreign to me. I can't figure out how to change any text anywhere in the shopping cart / checkout / account area

Comment: You need to search your code. I can't tell you if it is in the backend of Magento or not yet.

Comment: Go take a look thro every active shipping carrier under System->Configuration-Shipping Methods. I suspect the text will be set in one of those. Otherwise you need to as Kris says and get all the Magento codebase down (app/code/local and app/code/community are prob where it would be if hard coded) and do a find in file search!

Answer (score -1):

You edit frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml in this file

Comment: Don't edit the core!

Comment: Copy that file and paste your theme then edit that